# Axis2 WebServices with JSON objects

Tags: json, web-services, apache-axis, jettison

I'm trying to get Axis2 WebServices to work with JSON Objects for three days, and can't get it right.
They have to receive and return JSON so it can comunicate with an iPhone app. I've tried everything it the first seven pages in Google and got nothing.

I've already put the Message Formatters and Message Builders in axis2.xml. So as jettison jar in the lib folder.

Can someone help me, please? I need an example of how to make this to work.
Thanks!

Comment: what are the errors you get ?

Comment: None! I've made everything right. My method is returning an object, but axis2 is not parsing it. :/